# How to pass the production variable to Authorize.Net API?

Tags: python-3.x, authorize.net

I am working on getting the transactions on Authorize.Net API.
I am using the same code sample and the SDK says that in order to switch to the production environment, I need to set the environment variable on the controller.
The link is [here](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-python#switching-between-the-sandbox-environment-and-the-production-environment). I am not sure where should I add this line of code

```
createtransactioncontroller.setenvironment(constants.PRODUCTION)
```

Rest of the code is the [here](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-python/blob/master/TransactionReporting/get-merchant-details.py)

Is this the right way to use the controller

```
import os
import sys
import imp

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from authorizenet import apicontractsv1
from authorizenet.apicontrollers import getSettledBatchListController
from authorizenet.apicontrollers import createTransactionController
constants = imp.load_source('modulename', 'constants.py')



def get_settled_batch_list():
    """get settled batch list"""
    createTransactionController.setenvironment(constants.PRODUCTION)
    merchantAuth = apicontractsv1.merchantAuthenticationType()
```

Comment: Is this code working? Are you getting an error? If so, what error message do you get?

Comment: the error I get is the authentication error because I am passing the production userid and key and the API is pinging the sandbox api url

Comment: the code is by default hitting the SANDBOX API as they mentioned on git hub, I want to pass to the controller the PRODUCTION API. The problem here as I mentioned is I don't know how to pass the values to the controller.

Comment: Your code appears to be correct. Have you  used a debugger to verify you are executing this code path?

Comment: yes I did that, it's still taking the `sandbox` variable  instead of `production`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same error and the way I fixed it was I changed the file constants.py to credentials.py and then I changed the variable to MY_CONSTANTS but you can change them to be credentials if you want.

If it does doesn't work at that point you could try to hard code it instead with createtransactioncontroller.setenvironment('https://api2.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api')
but if you don't then leave it to be constants.PRODUCTION

```
    createtransactioncontroller = createTransactionController(createtransactionrequest)
    createtransactioncontroller.setenvironment(constants.PRODUCTION)
    # or createtransactioncontroller.setenvironment('https://api2.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api')
    createtransactioncontroller.execute()
```

I used a dictionary for my credentials(constants in your case) so mine looks a little different.

```
    import imp
    import os
    import sys
    import importlib
    from authorizenet.constants import constants
    from authorizenet import apicontractsv1
    from authorizenet.apicontrollers import createTransactionController

    from .credentials import MY_CONSTANTS

# retrieved from the constants file
merchantAuth = apicontractsv1.merchantAuthenticationType()
merchantAuth.name = MY_CONSTANTS['apiLoginId']
merchantAuth.transactionKey = MY_CONSTANTS['transactionKey']
```

I hope this helped you.